# Bad substittion in ksh

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I am trying to pass a function two variables, I would like to replace spaces with underscores for the file name, i.e.:

```
directory=<path to file>
file=<name of file>

my_function "$directory/${file// /_}"
```

This will work in bash and later ksh, however I am working on an older Solaris 9 box and the result is a bad substitution error.

Is there a clean way to achieve this functionality in an old KSH environment?

Comment: `${dir}/$(echo "$file"|sed 's/_/ /g')....`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! Although I am replacing spaces with underscores so sed 's/ /_/g'.

Comment: `tr` solution might be microscopically more efficient (I did up vote it). If you're going to use `sed`, I'd recommend the `printf "..." | sed '...'` as in the `tr` solution. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tr`:

```
my_function "$directory/$(printf '%s' "$file" | tr ' ' '_')"
```